# Custom page template for multiple pages

Tags: pages, page-template, child-pages

A site I'm currently working on has a page structure like this

```
About Us
|
|_People
| |
|  _ Person 1
|  _ Person 2
|  _ Person 3
|... etc ...
```

Every 'Person' page is a separate page, but they all have the same structure using a few ACF fields to display a person's bio, photo etc.

I know how to create a custom page template for one specific page, i.e. page-*slug*.php, but I want to use one page template for all of those subpages.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always make use of the `page_template` filter to tell WordPress to use a specific page template for all child pages of a certain parent. It is as easy as creating a special page template, lets call it `page-wpse-person.php`.

Now it is as easy as including that template whenever a child page of `people` is being viewed. For the sake of example, lets say the page ID of `people` is `10`

```
add_filter( 'page_template', function ( $template ) use ( &$post )
{
    // Check if we have page which is a child of people, ID 10
    if ( 10 !== $post->post_parent )
        return $template;

    // This is a person page, child of people, try to locate our custom page
    $locate_template = locate_template( 'page-wpse-person.php' );

    // Check if our template was found, if not, bail
    if ( !$locate_template )
        return $template;

    return $locate_template;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter. This was exactly what I was looking for and just set it up this way.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked for you. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to create a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) 'person', in which you include the custom fields. The [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) would then ensure that the `single-person.php` template is used for those posts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I prefer to stick to pages so in the admin panel I keep that same visual page structure which is easier to use for the editor. I went with Pieter's solution.